# Conditionally show image from the gallery or drawable resource using Coil and Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am trying to show an image from the gallery if anything chosen by the user, or an image from an image file in the drawable resource as the default image, which is not working. I am using Coil for Compose and added the dependency already. Here is the code:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private var imageUriState = mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null)

    private val selectImageLauncher = registerForActivityResult(GetContent()) { uri ->
        imageUriState.value = uri
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ImageSourceActivityScreen()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun ImageSourceActivityScreen() {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Image(
                painter = rememberImagePainter(
                    if (imageUriState != null) {
                        imageUriState.value
                    } else {
                        R.drawable.blank_profile_picture
                    }
                ),
                contentDescription = "profile image",
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
    ...
}
```

No error is showing, but the default image is also not showing. Please help to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Is the user chosen image working? Which versions of compose and coil are you using ?

Comment: Nothing was showing at all - even the rest of the UI (buttons)! Fixed it now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're comparing `imageUriState` with `null` which is always true

You have two options:

1. Specify painter depending on your state value

```
Image(
    painter = if (imageUriState.value != null) {
        rememberImagePainter(
            imageUriState.value
        )
    } else {
        painterResource(id = R.drawable.blank_profile_picture)
    },
    contentDescription = "profile image",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```

2. By default, coil won't display you a placeholder if you pass `null` as data, which generally makes sense. If you wanna see your placeholder both when there's no image, and when you're waiting image to be loaded, you can create such function:

```
@Composable
inline fun rememberImagePainter(
    data: Any?,
    @DrawableRes emptyPlaceholder: Int,
    builder: ImageRequest.Builder.() -> Unit = {},
): Painter {
    val painter = rememberImagePainter(
        data,
        builder = {
            placeholder(emptyPlaceholder)
            builder()
        }
    )
    if (data == null) {
        return painterResource(emptyPlaceholder)
    }
    return painter
}

// usage
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkyep.jpg",
        emptyPlaceholder = R.drawable.test,
    ),
    contentDescription = "profile image",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)
```

Comment: Got hints for where to look for the bug and found it! I was calling imageUriState without .value. Fixed that, and it is working now! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I tried the second solution, but it doesn't work for some strange reason! Even the rest of the UI doesn't show like my code!

Comment: Tried the first solution, with adding the `.value` part inside the `if` logic, which works. Thanks for showing the recommended way! Can you please check why the second solution doesn't work?

Comment: I've re-checked the second case and it seems fine, can't say what's exactly doesn't work in your case without seeing the full code

Comment: Can you please have a look at the code here: https://github.com/rawhasan/compose-exercises-image-source

Comment: @Hasan my bad, I expect coil to display placeholder for `null` data, but it doesn't. Check out updated second variant which may be useful for you

Comment: Thanks @Philip! The code is showing a lot of errors:

`Local inline functions are not yet supported in inline functions.`
`Inline function 'local final inline fun rememberImagePainter(data: Any?,
emptyPlaceholder: Int, builder: ImageRequest.Builder.() -> Unit = ...): ImagePainter defined in com.example.imagesource.MainActivity.ImageSourceActivityScreen.<anonymous>' cannot be recursive.`
`No value passed for parameter 'emptyPlaceholder'.`
`Type mismatch: inferred type is Painter but ImagePainter was expected.`

Comment: @Hasan updated my answer one more because of the last error(`Type mismatch`). `Local inline functions are not yet supported in inline functions`  this is because you've pasted my function inside an other function. It should be in top level, probably even in some other file where you store your custom composables which are used in many places of the project

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Philip! Learned a lot from your answer. I am accepting this answer since the first solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `builder` parameter to set a [`placeholder`](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/api/coil-base/coil.request/-image-request/-builder/placeholder.html):

```
val painter = rememberImagePainter(
    imageUriState.value,
    builder = {
        placeholder(R.drawable.blank_profile_picture)
    }
)
Image(
    painter,
    contentDescription = "profile image",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```

Comment: Got hints for where to look for the bug and found it! I was calling `imageUriState` without `.value`. Fixed that, and it is working now! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Found hints of where to look for the bug from @Gabriele Mariotti's answer. I was calling `imageUriState` without `.value`. Fixed that, and it is working now. Thanks, everyone for your help!

```
Image(
    painter = rememberImagePainter(
        if (imageUriState.value != null) {
            imageUriState.value
        } else {
            R.drawable.blank_profile_picture
        }
    ),
    contentDescription = "profile image",
    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```